# Google Chat somehow causes my wifi connection to drop

Tags: network, wifi, macbook-pro

I work at home, and for the past week or so, the wifi connection on my MacBook has been extremely flaky. Over the course of the day, the wifi will repeatedly disconnect and then reconnect about 10 seconds later. This occurs as infrequently as once every few hours, or as frequently as every 10 minutes.

If I look at my router (or run Network Diagnostics) when this happens, I can confirm that the actual *Internet* connection isn't dropping; it's just the wifi. Furthermore, the wifi network remains listed as a nearby network when the connection drops, so to me this suggests that the network itself is okay, and it's just my computer disconnecting and reconnecting for some reason.

Now for the twist: this appears to only happen when I'm signed onto Google Chat through iChat. I have never seen it happen otherwise (I guess it *could* just be coincidence, but that seems pretty unlikely since I've been observing it for about a week now).

What can I do about this? Is Google Chat really the culprit, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never exactly figured out what the issue is, and this might just be coincidence, but I recently upgraded to Lion (and installed Messages Beta over iChat) and have not seen this issue since. I'm going to tentatively say this is resolved...